# Rails 3 - Multiple Currencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, currency

If I do this:

```
number_to_currency(100,:locale=>'en-GB')
```

I'd expect to get something like this:

```
£100.00
```

But instead I'm getting

```
$100
```

This is the same if I pass in the locale :en, 'fr-FR' or whatever.

Does Rails have a default list of currencies based on locale, or do I have to setup the I18 mappings for **every country on the planet** myself?

Any help appreciated.

Tobin

Comment: You can do number_to_currency(100,:unit=>"£")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the locale file, the currency unit is defined via

```
number:
  currency:
    unit:    "$"
```

You have to do it yourself. This may help:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/locale/en.yml

Comment: Thanks, so I have to create this mapping for all countries!? :S

Comment: Yes. Most applications don't offer custom translations for every country on the planet, but they fall back to English for users from non-supported countries. I suppose that's one reason why there are no defaults for foreign currencies and so on.

Comment: there are already a lot of translations available: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale

Comment: Ok, thanks folks. I'll grab those files, should give me a head start.