# calculate payments in different currencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have table items wich have string "USD" or "EUR".
I create in my controller variable

```
 def index
    ...
    @currencydebt = CurrencyRate.find( :all, 
     :conditions => ["created_at < ? and currency_id = ?", Date.today, 2], 
     :order => ["created_at DESC"], :limit => 1 )
    ...
    end
```

witch find last currency USD

** in my view**

```
<% for res in @items %>
     <% for loc in @currencydebt %>
       <%= number_with_precision(((loc.rate.round(2)  * res.payment)), 2) %>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Аnd as a result showing paymant in currency USD.
But how can I do that would show up as a result if have string USD in items Payment result in USD, if have EUR in items Payment result in EUR?

**my ActiveRecord**

```
create_table "items", :force => true do |t|
  t.string    "name"
  t.string    "currency"
  t.decimal    "payment"
  ...
end

create_table "currency_rates", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "currency_id"
  t.decimal "rate"
  ...
end  

create_table "currencies", :force => true do |t|
  t.string "name"     #USD or EUR
  t.string "short_name"
end
```

Comment: Take a look at this Money gem and google currencies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199301/rails-3-1-multiple-currencies or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019939/ruby-on-rails-best-method-of-handling-currency-money

Comment: unfortunately i'm use rails 2.0 and don't use gems

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, handling currency is always tricky. There are gems to ease the pain like [this](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money).

To solve your immediate problem though, you must decide first on a base currency. So assuming you want to keep USD as the base currency, then use the gem to switch between whatever currency you want.

Comment: tnx for answer, but unfortunately i'm use rails 2.0